# How does abspath determine if a path is relative?

Tags: python, operating-system

I know that abspath can take either a file or a relative set of files and make a full path for them by prepending the current directory, as shown in these examples:

```
>>> os.path.abspath('toaster.txt.')
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\toaster.txt'

>>> os.path.abspath('i\\am\\a\\toaster.txt.')
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\i\\am\\a\\toaster.txt'
```

And a full path provided will be recognised as absolute and not prepend this path:

```
>>> os.path.abspath('C:\\i\\am\\a\\toaster.txt.')
'C:\\i\\am\\a\\toaster.txt'
>>> os.path.abspath('Y:\\i\\am\\a\\toaster.txt.')
'Y:\\i\\am\\a\\toaster.txt'
```

My question is how does abspath know to do this? This is on Windows, so is it checking for '@:' at the start (where @ is any alphabet character)?

If that is the case, how do the other OSes determine it? A Mac's '/Volumes/' path is less clearly distinguishable as a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to the [implementation in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cedd25ad8eeb45e486bba0b712154b79f0acae92/Lib/ntpath.py#L61), an absolute path on Windows 95 and Windows NT is being checked like this:

```
# Return whether a path is absolute. 
# Trivial in Posix, harder on Windows. 
# For Windows it is absolute if it starts with a slash or backslash (current 
# volume), or if a pathname after the volume-letter-and-colon or UNC-resource 
# starts with a slash or backslash. 


def isabs(s): 
    """Test whether a path is absolute""" 
    s = splitdrive(s)[1]
    return len(s) > 0 and s[0] in _get_bothseps(s)
```

This function is called by `abspath`, if `_getfullpathname` is not available. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the implementation of `_getfullpathname`.

The implementation of `abspath` (in case `_getfullpathname` is not available):

```
def abspath(path): 
    """Return the absolute version of a path.""" 
    if not isabs(path): 
        if isinstance(path, bytes): 
            cwd = os.getcwdb() 
        else: 
            cwd = os.getcwd() 
        path = join(cwd, path) 
    return normpath(path)
```

Comment: This is a very helpful answer! But I'm confused by one part of the page you quoted, it says 
**For Windows it is absolute if it starts with a slash or backslash (current volume)**
 Isn't that a relative path rather than absolute?

Comment: I just checked it on my Windows PC and indeed `\foo` refers to an absolute path in Windows, too. Precisely, the absolute path on the current volume - as the highlighted string states. Try it yourself by using the command line, going to some subfolder on `C:` and then `cd \Windows`. It will bring you to `C:\Windows` again.

Comment: Aha, now it makes sense to me. Thank you!